# Do the teachings of Bhagavad Gita help to defeat diabetes?

Tags: diabetes

As published in [Times of India](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/hyderabad/divine-words-can-defeat-diabetes-says-research/articleshow/65617410.cms) in 2018:

> Researchers say that the communication between Arjuna and Lord Krishna as enunciated in Bhagavad Gita could be utilised to cope with illness, especially chronic diseases such as diabetes.They are pointing to the verses (slokas) of Bhagavad Gita, which talk about various situations in life.

> “The Gita points out negative situations and goes on to showcase positive coping skills suggested by Lord Krishna and implemented by Arjuna,” the researchers said. Stating that diabetes is a lifestyle disease, which warrants a thorough change in one’s lifestyle, including changes in basic activities such as diet and exercise, the researchers said utilisation of the teachings of Bhagavad Gita could help cope with it.

Do the teachings of Bhagavad Gita, particularly the communication between Arjuna and Lord Krishna, assist with the defeat of diabetes?

Comment: Jay Shri Krishna,      I shouldn't have asked this question. How can I delete this question? Om Namah Shivaya. Hare Krishna

Comment: Why? You asked a question and received an answer. If you think it does answer, then "accept" it.

Comment: @Weather Vane If I honestly say, I don't feel I have recieved answer. Sorry but I want if this question deleted, it will better. Jay Shri Krishna Om Namah Shivaya Hare Krishna

Comment: Was my comment deleted, and if so why?

Comment: @Acccumulation: Yes, because it complained about an issue in the question that had been fixed in an edit and took a swipe at the motivations of a new user based on their religion which is unacceptable. Don't do that.

Comment: @HareKrishna: Sorry you don't like the answer, but you haven't given any reason why there is a problem with it.

Comment: I think that the question is still unclear. And I didn't take "a swipe at the motivations of a new user based on their religion". I stated that the people would be likely to take the OP's username into account when evaluating how good faith their question is.

Comment: There's also [hinduism.se], if you post this question there they'll probably give you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @Erik: But choosing a forum so you get told the outcome you want to hear is against a skeptical ethos. Better to be challenged.

Comment: @Oddthinking oh I definitely agree with that. it's better to be skeptical, but I'm not gonna force it on people who aren't looking for it :)

Answer (score 15):

The newspaper article is reporting on the publication of this paper:

- Kalra, B., Joshi, A., Kalra, S., Shanbhag, V. G., Kunwar, J., Singh Balhara, Y. P., Chaudhary, S., Khandelwal, D., Aggarwal, S., Priya, G., Verma, K., Baruah, M. P., Sahay, R., Bajaj, S., Agrawal, N., Pathmanathan, S., Prasad, I., Chakraborty, A., & Ram, N. (2018). *[Coping with Illness: Insight from the Bhagavad Gita.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6085948/)* Indian journal of endocrinology and metabolism, 22(4), 560–564. https://doi.org/10.4103/ijem.IJEM_228_17

This is not an experimental paper that describes empirical results from treating patients with diabetes.

This is not a literature review or meta-analysis combining the results of other experiments.

It is a religious tract, mining a religious document for statements that can be interpreted as offering good advice for diabetics.

e.g.

> Lord Krishna supports action, rather than grief or depression, as a means of coping with a stressful situation. Multiple slokas of the Gita reinforce this message, which is equally relevant for persons with diabetes.
>
> “…stand up, Arjuna, determined to fight”
>
> *tasmad uttishtha kaunteya, yuddhaya kritanischayaha.* 2:37
>
> “ …nor let your attachment be to inaction”
>
> *Ma karma phala he turbhur, mate sangastva karmanihi* 2:47

There is some actual advice (exercise, avoid depression, eat in moderation) in this tract that may be healthy, but there is no attempt to show:

- People reading the Bhagavad Gita are more likely to handle diabetes better.
- That their personal interpretation of the words is the intended interpretation or even a widely accepted interpretation.
- That the advice given is effective or efficacious.

In short, this is a religious sermon, not a scientific article.

Comment: @HareKrishna: It doesn't *measure* whether it is effective or not. It just assumes that it is.

Comment: @HareKrishna It's a theological paper, not a medical one. It deals with interpreting a religious source. Not with examining if its advice is sound in practice. The question it tries to answer is "What does the Shrimad Bhagavad Gita say about diabetes?". It does not answer the question if what it says is supported by medical observations.

Comment: @Phillipp I think I have found paper which backup some of findings of Bhagavad Gita as : "... Arjuna under duress exhibits elements of distorted thinking. Lord Krishna helps remedy this through a process akin to Cognitive Behavioral Therapy (CBT).We ascertain the analogies between the principles of Gita and CBT, grief emancipation, role transition, self-esteem, and motivation enhancement, as well as interpersonal and supportive psychotherapies. We advocate the pragmatic application of age old wisdom of the Gita..." Source: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3705702/  Jay Shri Krishna

Comment: @HareKrishna That would be a different question, but I suspect the answer will be similar. These articles look in a religious tract for statements which can be interpreted in support of a position, then assert that this interpretation is the correct one, and hence the original position is supported. Trouble is, all the scope for selection and interpretation means that you can do this for almost anything.  E.g. https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/20650/did-the-quran-predict-the-speed-of-light So the fact that someone has done this for the Gita and some illness means nothing.

Comment: @HareKrishna: This site is dedicated to scientific skepticism, which means evaluating claims against empirical evidence. The papers you cite are not scientific papers. They seek to find scripture to support their religious beliefs which is not an acceptable method here. There may be some claims in Bhagavad Gita we can test, but that wasn't the question.